# C Function pointers and platform abstraction layer

Tags: c, function, pointers, abstraction, platform

I'm trying to create a platform abstraction layer in C using function pointers, and not sure how best to do it. I have a platform.h that I want the user of the library to use which has the function pointer declarations in it. Then for windows I have a win32_platform.c file where I implement the functions. However not sure where I should assign the function pointers. Should I use an ifdef _WIN32 somewhere or do it in an "init" function? I'm not sure the best way :(

platform.h

```
extern f64 (*GetPlatformFrequency)(void);
/*Get the time in milliseconds*/
extern f64 (*GetHighresTimeInMilli)(f64);
/*Get a high-resolution time point for platform*/
extern f64 (*GetHighresTime)(void);
```

platform_win32.h

```
f64 win32_GetPlatformFrequency(void);
f64 win32_GetHighresTimeInMilli(f64 time);
f64 win32_GetHighresTime(void);
```

platform_win32.c

```
//Implementation details here
```

I tried using ifdefs and init functions for assigning function pointers to their specific platform but was getting "multiple redefinition" errors or "undefined" function errors.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but function pointers seems a bit weird here. You can just have a regular `.h` file declaring regular functions, and separate implementations in `.c` files for each platform. The build system for each platform builds the appropriate `.c` file for that platform.

Comment: It seems like you would still need an #ifdef in order to assign the function pointers, if they have different names. Seems like you could give the functions the same name but name the .c files differently and compile and link the different .o files depending on which platform you are on.

Comment: I happen to know that nginx does this so maybe take a look at it?  You only really to do this if you require switching a run-time.  If you know your target at compile time then it's cheaper map the platform specific function to a the abstract name with defines.

Comment: If you want to do this a run-time look a the factory method pattern.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestions! I don't need to switch at runtime. I'll go with the compile time method

Comment: The normal way would just be to provide a platform-independent header and then link the relevant .c file implementing the header.